# Need help for Logout user if browser close

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I try many types of code Like Using javascript,jquery but not possible

Need your help

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    var confirmationMessage = "\o/";
    e = e || window.event;

    var y = e.pageY || e.clientY;
    if(y < 0){
        createCookie("Window closed","YES",1);
    } else{
        createCookie("Window refress","YES",1);
    } 

});
```

in YIi2 Main.php

```
'enableAutoLogin' => false,
```

All thinks not working... :-(

[Please check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSa2j.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can see maximum login time with disable auto login to force logout user:

```
'user' => [
    'enableAutoLogin' => false,
    'authTimeout' => 300,
],
'session' => [

        'timeout' => 300,

    ],
```

see [authTimeout-detail](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-user#$authTimeout-detail)
with this config, when user be in page and do nothing after 5 min(300 sec), the login session has been expired, and when user close his/her browser and did not open it before 5 min, the session will expired!

Note: Do not change `autoRenewCookie` to `false`

Or try this:

```
$(window).unload( function () {
     jQuery.ajax({url:"logout_url", async:false})
} );
```

Comment: i already added but not working

```
'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'authTimeout' => 300,

```

Comment: Ok, I think your problem is in `session timeout` i edited my answer, check it ;) @askme

Comment: I need if user close browser or browser tab then logout force to relogin

Comment: If you are enforcing to do that with js, see my update

Comment: $(...).unload is not a function

Comment: i already try with javascript and jquery https://nimb.ws/qTvFOn

Comment: check Yii debugger, are you sure your logout link is correct ?!

Comment: Link is correct ajax is canceled if I close the browser

Comment: @askme So the solution is what I say first, You can reduce your auth time and session time, then when user close browser and didnt open it in less than 5 minutes, his/her session has been destroyed and user must login again, Notice : in User login form, don't check remember checkbox .

Comment: but I need if user close browser then reopen in at the time forced to relogin

Comment: @askme if you didn't set expire time for your coockies, then will expired after close browser. so in login model, set force false $rememberme

Comment: how to set force

Comment: go to common\models\LoginForm set $rememberMe to false,and in login() method, in second attribute of Yii::$app->user->login(), just set false

Comment: No once help me :-(